# Returning modified data to a template

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, django-queryset

I need to amend QuerySet data when i return it to a template.

for example, model.objects.all() returns a date (with other fields), but i also want to return the number of days since that date has passed. This is so that in the template, i can say "you last logged in 4 days ago".

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a built-in [template filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) to do this:

```
{{ myobject.datefield|timesince }}
```

But generally for this sort of thing, the easiest way is probably to define a custom method on the model:

```
def mymethod(self):
   today = datetime.datetime.today()
   since = today - self.datefield  # since is a datetime.timedelta object
   return since.days
```